# Using rasterio and matplotlib how can I create a window for an NDVI image to fit into?

Tags: python, numpy, rasterio, matplotlib

I am using Rasterio, Numpy, and Matplotlib. I created a window with the dimensions of 800x600 and plotted the band 5 for a Landsat 8 image, that worked just fine. I also have the nir image so then I calculated the ndvi of the red and nir bands from the Landsat8 image. What I am trying to do is put my ndvi image inside a 800x600 window. How might this be done? So far or the ndvi image it's giving me default dimensions of 7000x7000, I want to create the or use the same window of Window(2000,2000,800,6000)

Here is my code so far:

```
import rasterio
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


nirband = r"LC08_L1TP_015033_20170822_20170912_01_T1_B5.TIF"

redband =r"LC08_L1TP_015033_20170822_20170912_01_T1_B4.TIF"


#rasterio.windows.Window(col_off, row_off, width, height)
window = rasterio.windows.Window(2000,2000,800,600)

with rasterio.open(nirband) as src:
    subset = src.read(1, window=window)

plt.figure(figsize=(6,8.5))
plt.imshow(subset)
plt.title(f'Band 5 Subset')
plt.xlabel('Column #')
plt.ylabel('Row #')





rast = rasterio.open(nirband)
rast2 = rasterio.open(redband)
nir = rast.read(1)
red = rast2.read(1)


red = red.astype(float)
nir = nir.astype(float)
np.seterr(divide='ignore', invalid='ignore')


ndvi = np.empty(rast.shape, dtype=rasterio.float32)
check = np.logical_or ( red > 0, nir > 0 )
ndvi = np.where ( check,  (1.0*(nir - red )) / (1.0*( nir + red )),-2 )


plt.figure(figsize=(6,8.5))
plt.imshow(ndvi)
plt.title(f'NDVI')
plt.xlabel('Column #')
plt.ylabel('Row #')
```

This creates two plots one which is 800x600, the other ranges from 7000x7000, I think this is the default for the image. I am trying to have the same dimensions for my ndvi image as I have for my nir band image.

Here is my attempt at saving the NDVI as a GeoTIFF file:

```
with rasterio.open("LC08_L1TP_015033_20170822_20170912_01_T1_B5.TIF") as src:
    naip_data_ras = src.read()
    naip_meta = src.profile



with rasterio.open('MyExample.tif', 'w',**naip_meta) as dst:
    dst.write_band(1, naip_ndvi, window=window)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code. Just read the first two bands in, windowed as you want them, then perform the ndvi calculation on those rasters, resulting in an ndvi image of the same window size.

```
with rasterio.open(nirband) as src:
    nir = src.read(1, window=window)

with rasterio.open(redband) as src:
    red= src.read(1, window=window)

red = red.astype(float)
nir = nir.astype(float)
np.seterr(divide='ignore', invalid='ignore')

ndvi = np.empty(nir.shape, dtype=rasterio.float32)
check = np.logical_or ( red > 0, nir > 0 )
ndvi = np.where ( check,  (1.0*(nir - red )) / (1.0*( nir + red )),-2 )
```

Your problem was that you were re-loading your full red and nir bands as (7000 x 7000) rasters, then performing your ndvi calculation. What you should do (and what I've shown above) is to load in your red and nir bands for only the windowed area, *then* perform the ndvi calculation.

Comment: Thank you! How would I do it the first way? i'd like to have either another window or the same window and just have it set up like Window(2000,2000,800,600) and have the ndvi tucked in there.

Comment: Also, all I have access to right now is the two bands B5 and B4. So just using those I'm trying to create the same dimension box for NIR and NDVI.

Comment: Here is an image of the output from Spyder, I'd like to have both windows with the same dimensions and subset area, so col_off and col_on_ would have to be the same: https://imgur.com/a/gf0ohAp

Comment: @yuen2 Did you compute the NDVI yourself or get it from another location? Does it have the same dimensions as the Landsat images?

Comment: Yes NDVI is calculate from this line in the code down: ndvi = np.empty(rast.shape, dtype=rasterio.float32)…. now just trying to put that into a dimension box with Window(2000,2000,800,600)

Comment: When I use the last 5 lines of code it prints out the NDVI with matplotlib and gives the dimensions 7000x7000, i'm guessing that's the default dimensions of the landsat8 image but not 100%/

Comment: @yuen see updated comment. Let me know if that doesn't work for you.

Comment: SUCCESS! YES THIS IS EXACTLY RIGHT. So it looks like it was just a matter of looping it first? THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: @yuen2 I added a little explanatory text to the answer...there is no looping!

Comment: Not to be rude but would you know how to save the NDVI image with georefernces in GeoTIFF format?

Comment: I see, no looping! I guess the part that made it seem like looping was the colon and then the tab. Guess that's just the format for opening a raster in rasterio.

Comment: @yuen2 Look at the rasterio examples for how to write your windowed geotiff--I have code I can give you that uses gdal (which is what rasterio ultimately uses) but it would require a bit of explanation. I think you'd want to get the georeferencing info from the src object when you're loading the nir or red bands, then pass it back to rasterio to write the ndvi.

Comment: Actually having some difficulty with saving it. Was there a tutorial you know of in particular?

Comment: seemed like this was a good one but when I save it it just comes out all black (posted some code to show my work): https://www.earthdatascience.org/courses/earth-analytics-python/multispectral-remote-sensing-in-python/export-numpy-array-to-geotiff-in-python/

Comment: You should create another question; comments aren't for solving additional problems.

Comment: Thankfully was able to figure that one out! Although ndvi is all in gray

Comment: Probably just need to change your display parameters.

Comment: That's what it was. Not I am trying to reproject only problem is I don't see US alberbs projection as an option in Rasterio. I tried 'aea' but is doesn't exist. Any ideas?

Comment: I use gdal for reprojecting geotiffs. You can also easily use QGIS which uses gdal. (Rasterio uses gdal as well). I use epsg codes to do the transformations--you can find them here: https://epsg.io/